# Receiving "cannot find symbol error" on line 17

Tags: java

The symbol is there which is a ";", so I'm not sure what the problem in syntax is.

```
//Vet Application
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class VetApp
{
public static void main(String[] paramArrayOfString)
{
Dog newDog1 = new Dog();
Dog newDog2 = new Dog(2, "Ruff");
System.out.println();

System.out.println();
newDog1.print();
System.out.println();
newDog2.print();
```

**Scanner localScanner = new Scanner (System.in);**

```
System.out.print("What is the new breed of the first dog? ");
int i = localScanner.nextInt();
newDog1.setBreed(i);
System.out.println();
System.out.println();
newDog1.print();

System.out.print("What is the breed of the second dog? ");
i = localScanner.nextInt();
newDog2.setBreed(i);
System.out.println();
System.out.println();
newDog2.print();

System.out.print("What sound does the first dog make? ");
String str = localScanner.next();
newDog1.setSound(str);
System.out.println();
System.out.println();
newDog1.print();
```

(Some of the program is omitted)

Here is the error message:

```
c:\jwork>javac VetApp.java
MontelWhite_VetApp.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
Scanner localScanner = new Scanner (System.in);
^
symbol:   class Scanner
location: class VetApp
MontelWhite_VetApp.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
Scanner localScanner = new Scanner (System.in);
                           ^
symbol:   class Scanner
location: class VetApp
2 errors
```

I also have the "Dog" class source code if needed.
What am I missing/forgetting?

Comment: Add `import java.util.Scanner` on top of your class file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add the import for `java.util.Scanner`. So add it on top of your class file, to look as below:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class VetApp {
    /* Code omitted */
}
```